# Installing php-font-lib in Joomla libraries namespacing

Tags: autoload

I am currently trying to install [php-font-lib](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib) in joomla, i have been working with custom libraries in joomla for the last 3 hours, So I have absolutely no idea whats going on.

I have Joomla 3.3.

I have gotten it to kind of work, if i remove the namespacing from a file and call it via:
`jimport('fontlib.Font');`

then i tried the following:
 `JLoader::registerNamespace('FontLib', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/fontlib/');`

but i still can not seem to call the Font class.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it.

I copied `php-font-lib` in the path shown in the image below.

[image]

**Using jimport** (with basically just replaces dots with slashes), you can choose to use the Autoloader provided by `php-font-lib`, which might decouple you nicely from Joomla.

```
jimport('php-font-lib.src.FontLib.Autoloader');

$font = \FontLib\Font::load('Norasi.ttf');
var_dump($font);
```

**Using the Joomla Autoloader**

```
JLoader::registerNamespace('FontLib', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/php-font-lib/src/');

$font = \FontLib\Font::load('Norasi.ttf');
var_dump($font);
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Wow, Thank you... went with using jimport.. the Joomla Autoloader didn't work out..

Comment: Nice to hear that. JLoader should have worked as well, tested myself in 3.3. Anyway, glad I could help.